# Preserve the order of selected objects

Tags: fabricjs

I'm selecting multiple objects on the canvas (holding down the Shift key) and my code relies on the order of selection (I need to use the first selected object as a reference for group operation).
I noticed that sometimes order is preserved when doing the selection and sometimes it does not. While debugging I discovered the following code in the source of fabric.js:

```
_createGroup: function(target) {
  var objects = this.getObjects(),
      isActiveLower = objects.indexOf(this._activeObject) < objects.indexOf(target),
      groupObjects = isActiveLower
        ? [this._activeObject, target]
        : [target, this._activeObject];
  this._activeObject.isEditing && this._activeObject.exitEditing();
  return new fabric.ActiveSelection(groupObjects, {
    canvas: this
  });
}
```

Thus the order depends on the Z-order of the first two objects being selected (this function gets called when single selection transforms into multiple selection after adding the second object).

Any advice on how to achieve my goal and ignore the Z-order? I can "undo" this reordering in my code, checking for Z-order myself and swapping the objects back into their "natural" order, but it just sounds crazy.

When working around this feature the option `preserveObjectStacking` should be set to true, or the selection order will be restored back to "wrong" one during render.

Comment: I'm working around this currently by keeping my own array of selected objects using event handlers `selection:created` and `selection:updated` but it doesn't look very elegant either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can confirm you that there is no way to keep it ordered unless you do what you are doing.

Please if you think this is a bad thing, a missing feature or something a dev just should not be faced with, just open a ticket on github issue tracker for fabricjs